# How and where did Walter Priestly (Priestley) come to America?

Tags: england, immigration, new-york-state

My 2nd Great Grandfather came to America through the port of New York around November 1857 according to his naturalization record.  He was born in England on June 18, 1836 or 1837.  Any idea on how I can find out where he came from to NY? Also where I can find information about where he ended up after he came through NY? I have him in Denmark, MN in 1880 and after but a blank from 1857 to 1880.  There were rumors in the family that he came through Canada but not sure.  I am also a blank from before he came here. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! While you are waiting for answers, try searching the site for questions about other immigrant ancestors and see if they help you answer your question.  Also look at other questions about New York State. You can find out more about how the site works in the [help] and in our companion [meta].